# Dual 1440p on Radeon HD 7770 and compatibility with FX-770m

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi, discrete-graphics

I have a Radeon HD 7770 in my desktop with DVI-D I am currently using for a 1440p Crossover monitor. Is there a cheap way to use any of the other ports (Displayport 1.2, HDMI) to work with another of these monitors, which only has a DVI-D input; specifically are there any adapters that don't blow off the wallet which would work?

Also, will any 1440p monitor work with Quadro FX-770M, as I have a Dell Precision M4400 which I would like to use with a monitor that goes above FHD.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Radeon HD7770 has DisplayPort, it should have two seperated, digital video output lines. Adapter should be cheap, as you convert digital DVI-D(D for Digital) to digital DisplayPort.
In Poland they cost around 15 EUR, so they should cost around the same in your country.
However, I don't think that HD7770 is capable of running second monitor any higher then 1080p (but I don't exclude such possibility!).

As for the second case, according to nVidia documentation:

http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/57865/LC_Quadro_FAM_Aug08_US_LowRes.pdf

You have both dual digital and dual analog line, so you should be capable of using 1440p monitor.
Also please take a look at note in nVidia docs, that states that max. resolution of Quadro FX-770M depends on the OEM, as they can for ex. cut down max. resolution in their configs.

About additional two monitors for your mobile workstation:

I've digged through several Dell Precision related sites and most of them states that Precision series need additional dock stations (300$) for the 2nd monitor output.

Comment: Thanks! I had previously looked but didn't find that part.

Comment: I've made an edit about 2 additional monitors for your Dell Precision. It seems you can only use one additional monitor without using their 'special' docking station with video output replicator. Clever from them, as Quadro will natively manage two digital outputs, but, well... money, money, money.